I'm getting the following error while trying to implement phone authentication using firebase in my react js project

On clicking the send otp button, it gives the following error message:-

Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'appVerificationDisabledForTesting')

It should show a captcha:- I'm not a robot , and send the otp in the mobile number.
Following is the code :
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Link, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { Form, Alert } from "react-bootstrap";
import { Button } from "react-bootstrap";
import "react-phone-number-input/style.css";
import PhoneInput from "react-phone-number-input";
import { useUserAuth } from "../../context/UserAuthContext";

const PhoneAuth = () => {
  const [error, setError] = useState("");
  const [number, setNumber] = useState("");
  const [flag, setFlag] = useState(false);
  const [otp, setOtp] = useState("");
  const [result, setResult] = useState("");
  const { setUpRecaptha } = useUserAuth();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const getOtp = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(number);
    setError("");
    if (number === "" || number === undefined)
      return setError("Please enter a valid phone number!");
    try {
      const response = await setUpRecaptha(number);
      setResult(response);
      setFlag(true);
    } catch (err) {
      setError(err.message);
    }
  };

  const verifyOtp = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setError("");
    if (otp === "" || otp === null) return;
    try {
      await result.confirm(otp);
      navigate("/home");
    } catch (err) {
      setError(err.message);
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className="p-4 box">
        <h2 className="mb-3">Firebase Phone Auth</h2>
        {error && <Alert variant="danger">{error}</Alert>}
        <Form onSubmit={getOtp} style={{ display: !flag ? "block" : "none" }}>
          <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formBasicEmail">
            <PhoneInput
              defaultCountry="IN"
              value={number}
              onChange={setNumber}
              placeholder="Enter Phone Number"
            />
            <div id="recaptcha-container"></div>
          </Form.Group>
          <div className="button-right">
            <Link to="/login">
              <Button variant="secondary">Cancel</Button>
            </Link>
            &nbsp;
            <Button type="submit" variant="primary">
              Send Otp
            </Button>
          </div>
        </Form>

        <Form onSubmit={verifyOtp} style={{ display: flag ? "block" : "none" }}>
          <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formBasicOtp">
            <Form.Control
              type="otp"
              placeholder="Enter OTP"
              onChange={(e) => setOtp(e.target.value)}
            />
          </Form.Group>
          <div className="button-right">
            <Link to="/login">
              <Button variant="secondary">Cancel</Button>
            </Link>
            &nbsp;
            <Button type="submit" variant="primary">
              Verify
            </Button>
          </div>
        </Form>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default PhoneAuth;

import { createContext, useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import {
    createUserWithEmailAndPassword,
    signInWithEmailAndPassword,
    onAuthStateChanged,
    signOut,
    GoogleAuthProvider,
    signInWithPopup,
    RecaptchaVerifier,
    signInWithPhoneNumber
} from "firebase/auth";
import { auth } from "../firebase.init";

const userAuthContext = createContext();

export function UserAuthContextProvider({ children }) {
    const [user, setUser] = useState({});

    function logIn(email, password) {
        return signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
    }
    function signUp(email, password) {
        return createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
    }
    function logOut() {
        return signOut(auth);
    }
    function googleSignIn() {
        const googleAuthProvider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
        return signInWithPopup(auth, googleAuthProvider);
    }
    function setUpRecaptha(number) {
        const recaptchaVerifier = new RecaptchaVerifier(
          "recaptcha-container",
          {},
          auth
        );
        recaptchaVerifier.render();
        return signInWithPhoneNumber(auth, number, recaptchaVerifier);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        const unsubscribe = onAuthStateChanged(auth, (currentuser) => {
            console.log("Auth", currentuser);
            setUser(currentuser);
        });

        return () => {
            unsubscribe();
        };
    }, []);

    return (
        <userAuthContext.Provider
            value={{ user, logIn, signUp, logOut, googleSignIn , setUpRecaptha }}
        >
            {children}
        </userAuthContext.Provider>
    );
}

export function useUserAuth() {
    return useContext(userAuthContext);
}

Above is the code of PhoneAuth.js file and UserAuthContext.js file, please help me solve the above error.
